# Table variable losses scale for decimal being stored in nvarchar sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have user defined table type `Geo` with a field name as `latitude nvarchar(50)`. 
When I try to load this table with a data table from stored procedure I lost the decimal scale,
eg.
if latitude is `19.127423490000002` I get only `19.1274`. 
I can't change the `nvarchar(50)` to `decimal` since I have chance of getting alphabets like `N/A` or `not applicable`.

DataTable

Lat
19.127423490000002

```
 public int ProcessGeo(DataTable dtGeo)
{
    SqlParameter[] paramList = new SqlParameter[1];
    paramList[0] = new SqlParameter("@Geo", dtGeo);
    paramList[0].TypeName = "Geo";
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spu_Geo", paramList);
}
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Geo] AS TABLE(
    [Latitude] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
GO
sql trace

declare @p1 dbo.Geo
insert into @p1 values(19.127423490000002)


exec spu_Geo @Geo=@p1

CREATE procedure [dbo].[spu_Geo]    
(    
@Geo as Geo ReadOnly,      
)    
As    
Begin    

 insert into Geos ( Latitude)    
   select Latitude from @Geo
  END
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Of course, you've not shown any code, but I run `declare @g Geo;insert into @g (latitude) values (CONVERT(decimal(38,8),10.12312312));select * from @g` where `Geo` is a UDT with `latitude` an `nvarchar(50)` and it produces a result with 8 decimal places. So please actually produce some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It will be working fine from sql management studio. It will fail when you send a datatable from ado.net

Comment: So, edit your question and show us some code. That are an infinite number of ways that this might have gone wrong. Do you expect us to test out every scenario?

Comment: You are refering to a table Geos in your stored procedure. If you check the Latitude definition in that table, I imagine you will discover a datatype you didn't expect. That is most likely the place for the cutoff

Comment: even in the geos table latitude is nvarchar(50)

Comment: What is the type of 19.12...? in the statement: insert into @p1 values(19.127423490000002) I would make an explicit cast if I were you.

Comment: Paul I can't make an explicit cast  in at insert statement because it happens internally in .NET framework. I found it in the sql profiler trace.